# Mount file system which is a SQL Server filestream

Tags: mount, samba, mssql

We've got a web app (.NET 8.0) which uses the [File API to save and load files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) from a SQL Server's `FileTable`. In practice, this means that the web app can rely on a "virtual" share to load and file saves  (which get automatically persisted on the db).

Now, we're moving the app to a Linux docker container and we're trying to set up the folder mapping. Before going into docker, we've thought about setting everything on a Linux box and we're having some issues with the smb share on the SQL Server machine.

Whenever we try to mount its complete path, we end up with an access denied exception

```
mount -t cifs //machine/sql_instance_folder/database/filetable -o username=...,password=...
```

However, if we just use the top shared folder, everything works out as expected:

```
mount -t cifs //machine/sql_instance_folder -o username=...,password=...
```

After running the previous command, we're able to get into the subfolders (ie, we can `cd` into `database/filetable`) and everything works out properly.

Can't we mount a "shared subfolder" when the smb share is using SQL Server's file stream?

Thanks.